# How can I skip rows with digits when i need to capture digits later .net regex

Tags: .net, regex

I am capturing data in a file containing different sized numbers, and the first two rows contain a date and a time as you can see below.

I can pull the data with no issues, and I have tried matching but not capturing these data points but this kills all of the output. and as far as I have tried I cannot tell it to skip digits since that will exclude everything.

the **tab delimited** file i am searching with **EXPRESSO** is:

```
    8/10/2016   8/10/2016   8/10/2016
    15:41:56    15:41:56    15:41:56
    100.6   100.6   100.6
    237 237 237
    239 239 239
    238.9   238.9   238.9
    63  63  63
    66  66  66
    65  65  65
    136 136 136
    134 134 134
    135 135 135
```

the code i am currently using for testing is:

```
    (?:[^\t]*\t*){2}(?<Data>[^\s]*)
```

the output is (currently capturing 3rd row, can capture any of them as long as output is what I need):

```
    8/10/2016
    15:41:56
    100.6
    237
    239
    238.9
    63
    66
    65
    136
    134
    135
```

the output i need is:

```
    100.6
    237
    239
    238.9
    63
    66
    65
    136
    134
    135
```

How can i make sure that my captured data does not include the first 2 rows with date and time?

I am using expresso windows application to test, and in design mode tab i have: Compiled, Ignore White, Multiline, and Culture invariant CHECKED.

I am also naming my data set because i have other apps calling it...

Comment: RegEx is not the right tool.  There are many many tools available whose sole purpose is to parse delimited text files.  .NET includes one called [`TextFieldParser`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualbasic.fileio.textfieldparser(v=vs.110).aspx).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should precede the regex you have with a lookahead to ensure that the line you're matching has only the characters you want:

```
(?=[\d.\t]+$)(?:[^\t]*\t*){2}(?<Data>[^\s]*)
```

It is looking for a line that contains only digits, decimals, and tabs.

**Note:** you should also clean up the following items.

- `(?:[^\t]*\t+){2}`: changed to ensure there's at least one tab before the "Data" capture group
- `(?<Data>\S*)`: `\S`is equivalent to `[^\s]`, but cleaner

Comment: Huge help! and also thank you for the clean up items!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you need to capture the last group of digits and `.`, after a tab:

```
\t(?<Data>[\d\.]+)$
```